# How do I centre my navigation for just mobile devices? CSS

Tags: html, css

For the computer I have the navigation set on the left, but for the phone I would like it to be centred in the display. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

*html file*

```
    <div id="topNav">
    <nav class="navigation" role="navigation"
    <ul>
        <li class="Work">
            <a href="Work.html">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="About">
            <a href="About.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="Contact">
            <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

*Css file:*

```
    topNav
    {
    display:block;
    }

    ul,li
    {
    list-style-type: none!important;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    max-width: 95%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 6%;
    font-size:25px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1%;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    float:left;
    }

    /* iphone */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    topNav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
      }
    }
```

I'm very new to this so it's like trying to speak a language i don't understand. So thanks for the help in advance,

Have a good day!

Comment: topNav -> #topNav, you should use id selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one :

```
<div id="topNav">
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
<ul>
    <li class="Work">
        <a href="Work.html">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="About">
        <a href="About.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Contact">
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#topNav{
    display:block;
    }
ul li{
    list-style-type: none!important;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1%;
    float:left;
    }

    /* iphone */

@media (max-width : 480px) and (min-width : 320px) {
    #topNav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 239px;
    }
    ul{
        padding:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works on the phone. Except now on the computer the navigation is too far left and cut off from the screen. I will include a screenshot in a minute

Comment: You're welcome. Did you added any codes yet ? Coz it's working fine here.

Comment: Yeah! I've corrected it once more as might you have been using padding in ul.  Update it from the above if needed. :)

Comment: well, its the same one as mine!! I said in my answer that make sure you have `width` set on `#topNav`

Comment: Also, if i'd like to increase the gap between the three links, how would i go about doing so?

Comment: @ppinzon You can add margin there.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last piece of code to this -

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
#topNav { /* you missed # before topNav */
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

and make sure #topNav has a width set on it which is less than device width, so that you can check it is aligned in the center or not?

if the above one didn't work, also try this -

```
nav {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Ok so I tried both but with no luck, their still on the left hand side of the display.

Comment: @ppinzon not only the correction, add `margin: auto` also as I have described in my answer, have you already tried that?? still not working?

Comment: Ok so I added margin: auto to the @media but it still didn't work

Comment: the @media includes display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin: auto;

Comment: @ppinzon also make sure you are seeing it in mobile device whose screen width is between `320px` and `480px`, if you are seeing in desktop and resizing the window to see it is working or not then it will not work,

Comment: No I am using an application called iPhoney which replicates the iPhone. (I tested it with other website responsive sites and they all worked. Also my images that i have respond just fine on the application, just having a hard time with the navigation)

Comment: @ppinzon try this thing at last - remove all the code inside @media, dont remove the @media statement, and after that paste this code inside the @media and see if it works or not - `ul {
        width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
      }`

Comment: @ppinzon sorry I forgot to tell you to remove the `float: left` from `ul, li` instead use `display: inline-block;` check this fiddle it is working - http://jsfiddle.net/pm8wabga/2/ don't pay attention to the borders, I've just set for testing.

Comment: That didn't work either. All it did was put the links one onto of another in 3 rows. But it didn't go in the middle of the display

Comment: @ppinzon check the fiddle I have linked, its working or not?? there is something else which might be causing problem.. also in the @media query change `min-device-width` to `min-width` and similarly for the `height` also and then check once again. Hope you get something different this time!

Answer (score 0):

See if this works!

CSS

```
.clearfix{clear:both}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) /*for small screen like mobile*/
{
  ul{border:1px solid red}
  li{float:left;padding:5px}
}
@media screen and (min-width:321px)  /*for screen larger than mobile*/
{
  li
    {
       list-style-type: none!important;
       font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
       display: block;
       max-width: 95%;
       margin-left: 5%;
       margin-top: 6%;
       font-size:25px;
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: 100;
       letter-spacing: -1px;
       float:left;
       border:1px solid red;
    }
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="topNav">
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
<ul>
    <li class="Work">
        <a href="Work.html">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="About">
        <a href="About.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Contact">
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Do come back if you still face the problem!

Comment: instead of the links all being on one line, one of the words went underneath the other two, along with red lines across the words. And didn't centre

Comment: Please post a screenshot if you can.! This will be more helpful.

Comment: I tried but the website says I need at least 10 reputation in order to post an image

Comment: Oh.! well then you may post it on imgur and paste the link here. As in my browser, I set up everything and got no issues.!

Comment: strange, how come it comes out different on my end?